# Handle variables not in datatype

Tags: sml, smlnj

What I wish to accomplish is to pass strings and booleans into a list. The 'switch' operator switches the first two elements of type input, the 'and' operator ands the first two elements.

However, how would I add an error string to the list ("error") if I wanted to 'and' a boolean and a string? Also, SMl does not accept `x::y::xs` what should I put instead since I would like to switch regardless of type.

```
datatype input = Bool_value of bool | String_Value of string | Exp_value of string
datatype bin_op = switch | and

fun helper(switch, x::y::xs) = y::x::stack 
    |   helper(and, Bool_value(x)::Bool_value(y)::xs) = Bool_value(x and y)::xs
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`and` is a keyword, so you change the `bin_op` to `switch | and_op`. `x::y::zs` is perfectly valid sml. In the first line of the helper function `stack` is not defined. Finally, the keyword to "and" two booleans together in sml is `andalso`.

Here is code that compiles:

```
datatype input = Bool_value of bool | String_Value of string | Exp_value of string
datatype bin_op = switch | and_op

fun helper(switch, x::y::xs) = y::x::xs 
| helper(and_op, Bool_value(x)::Bool_value(y)::xs) = Bool_value(x andalso y)::xs
```

There are unmatched patterns, but I assume you either left them out or will put them in later.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're building an interpreter for a dynamically typed
language.  If that is true, I would distinguish between the abstract syntax
of your program and the error handling of the interpreter, regardless of
whether you use exceptions or values to indicate error. For example,

```
datatype value = Int of int
               | Bool of bool
               | String of string

datatype exp = Plus of Exp * Exp
             | And of Exp * Exp
             | Concat of Exp * Exp
             | Literal of value

exception TypeError of value * value

fun eval (Plus (e1, e2)) = (case (eval e1, eval e2) of
                                (Int i, Int j) => Int (i+j)
                              | bogus => raise TypeError bogus)
  | eval (And (e1, e2)) = (case eval e1 of
                               Bool a => if a
                                         then ...
                                         else ...
                             | bogus => ...)
  | eval (Concat (e1, e2)) = (case (eval e1, eval e2) of
                                  (String s, String t) => String (s^t)
                                | bogus => raise TypeError bogus)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this looks similar with what I have seen done with interpreters.